# Probability without replacement of rhinos

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Working on a statistics assignment, just have a question that I can't get and I was looking for an explanation.

"There are 3160 White Rhinos and 11330 Black Rhinos.  If 5 rhinos are selected at random what is the probability that:
i. exactly two of the rhinos selected are white rhinos?
ii.  at least two of the rhinos selected are white rhinos"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: For ii) do you know how to find the complement?

Comment: There are $ 3160 + 11330 \choose 5$ combinations of rhinos possible. Can you figure out how many of them contain exactly 2 white rhinos?